# can not able to see the category in magento

Tags: uiactivitycategory

Magento Category is not showing after login [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skbgC.png)

[can not able to see the category in magento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skbgC.png)

Comment: [Maybe this one can help?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/23672/17249)

Comment: can you elaborate little bit more.

Comment: plz check the attachment .......

Comment: Magenta would be the site which could help you. But 1. It may ne a duplicate 2. as it stands the question might not be well received. Take a look to their site and help.

Comment: can you send me your email id ....so i can explain you everything ..

Comment: plz check this url  https://prnt.sc/h91397  .you can understand easily

Comment: plz check this url https://prnt.sc/h91397 .you can understand easily ....thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @WasimAkram - You also should read [ask]. Especially since you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @Enigmativity.. it is extreamly sorry to say that i will not ask the same questions here with the screenshots...lets take it easy ..more talk more solution

Comment: @WasimAkram - I am taking it easy. I'm just trying to let you know what the expected kinds and quality of questions are for this site. And, also, you really didn't actually ask a question - screenshots or otherwise.

Comment: @ Enigmativity .ok Sir i will ask a questions with brief and i am expecting from you to get the answer as early as possible .hope so..thanks for your kind reminder.......

Answer (score 0):

Check the developer tool bar it may contain some javascript error if not , try to replace the maento core files with new files, please be sure that the new files is the same version with current installation

Comment: Thank for your kind suggestion .I got the solution and now it's working perfectly.

Comment: i did not get any reply from anyone .can we have good solution from your end ...its very urgents..